# yii2 how to get relations and get title of id using foreign key

Tags: activerecord, yii

i have model of events , and one event have one project , one to one association and i have write function in Event model to get project as below

```
 public function getprojects() {
    return $this->hasOne(app\models\Project::className(), ['id' => 'projectid']);
}
```

and below is code of my controller

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $project = $model->project;
            return $this->redirect(['eventdetail', 'id' => $model->id, 'project' => $project]);
        }
```

and Detail view code is

```
 <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'projectid',
            'userid',
            'milestone',
            'datetime',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

I want to print Title of project instead of projectid , and we get title from associated table how i get title and print in detail view

Answer (score 3):

**1)** The easiest way if you only need text value is to change `projectId` to `projects.title`:

```
'attributes' => [
    'projects.title',
],
```

Also according label will be taken from `Projects` model.

**2)** For more complex situations and different formatiing you can call any model method to retrieve desired data.

Example:

```
'attributes' => [
    [        
        'attribute' => 'avatar',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => $model->getAvatar(),
    ],
],
```

Comment: <?=
    DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
            'projects.title',
            'userid',
            'milestone',
            'datetime',
        ],
    ])
    ?>  with error message Class 'app\models\app\models\Project' not found

Comment: In `getProjects()` relation try to add leading slash like that: `\app\models\Project::className()` or declare it in use section like so: use `app\models\Project::className()`, then in relation change to `Project::className()`.

Comment: chane model to  public function getproject() {
        return $this->hasOne(Project::className(), ['id' => 'projectid']);
    } and it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

To get relation data in DetaileView you can use `magic methods`.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'id',
             array(
                'attribute' => 'projectid',
                'value' => $model->project->title,
            )
            'userid',
            'milestone',
            'datetime',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

**And change relation code in your model to this:**

First, where page begin after `namespace` add

```
use app\models\Project;
```

Second, if you have one to one relation, call function in camelcase `getProject`, and `getProjects` is for one to many relation.

```
 public function getProject() {
    return $this->hasOne(Project::className(), ['id' => 'projectid']);
}
```